# Delete iCloud account without removing photos

Tags: iphone, icloud

My boyfriend bought me an iPhone 4 a year ago off a friend of a friend and I have since had a baby, so it is full with 700 odd pics which I want to keep safe of my baby boy on iCloud.

Thing is I've went to Settings → iCloud and the guy's iCloud is still logged in. I went to press delete so I could put my Apple ID in but it says it will wipe all pictures/data off the iPhone (obviously don't want to risk losing all my pictures of baby).

How do I set up my own iCloud and delete old person's without losing all the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup pictures to your computer.
2. Log out and log in with your iCloud account.
3. Transfer pictures back to your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow certain things before disconnecting your iCloud account..

First you need to download some files to the local storage. If you have iWork documents stored on the cloud, then visit the iCloud website from a computer and sign in (link in Resources).

Visit the "Pages" section, select the documents you wish to save and click the Settings icon, which looks like a small gear. Choose "Download Documents."

Repeat this process with your Keynote and Numbers apps. You don't need to back up photos, because the iCloud Photo Stream feature just displays the last 30 days of photos stored in your local camera roll.

Remove your old account on iOS devices by returning to the iCloud menu and tapping "Delete Account."

Acknowledge that your documents and photo stream will be removed from the device by pressing "Delete." When the prompt asks what to do with contacts, calendars, reminders, and Safari information, tap on the "Keep" option. This preserves your data on your local hard drive.

Hope this helps... !!!